# 503 RNFR command not understood

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, ftp-server

I'm using a (cheap branded) local media station as an FTP server and I'm using FIleZilla to transfer files to it.
When I try to move or rename a file located on the media station, I'm getting

```
Command:    RNFR [filename]
Response:   503 Command not understood.
```

I don't know whether this is because of an old or corrupted FTP version (it's a device older than 5 years and I think there are no updates available).
Is there an alternative to perform FTP rename or move commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an alternative to perform FTP rename or move commands?

If you have telnet or SSH access to the machine you could do the renaming their. If not you might try to use the FTP SITE command with "mv from-name to-name". But I doubt that the server will support this if it does not even support the standard way of FTP to rename files.

Apart from that the only alternative is probably to download the file, remove it on the server and upload it again with a different name.

Comment: If you can login to the machine with SSH or telnet you can of course do the renaming their.

Comment: Of course that's the only alternative. I would have preferred a local operation.
Moving files from/to media station with FTP is a pain: it mostly stops responding during transfers; initially I thought is was because it is connected to wifi and sometimes it happens to all my devices to temporarily detach from network, but when I connected it to cable it had the same behavior, so I guess it's just a junk media station..
When I transfer files to it via FTP I keep pinging it from the source hoping it helps maintaining the connection.

Comment: I thought about using SSH, but always got connection refused

    ssh admin@192.168.0.4
    ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.4 port 22: Connection refused